# VBA ListBox.Selected always return false

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create ListBox that show up when clicking a button. and get list data from an array. but for some reason ListBox.Selected always False even though I clicked the ListBox.

```
Sub Rectangle2_Click()

Dim MyList(10) As String
MyList(0) = "data1"
MyList(1) = "data2"
MyList(2) = "data3"
MyList(3) = "data4"
MyList(4) = "data5"
MyList(5) = "data6"
MyList(6) = "data7"
MyList(7) = "data8"
MyList(8) = "data9"
MyList(9) = "data10"
MyList(10) = "data11"

Dim xSelShp As Shape 
Dim xSelLst As Variant
Dim I As Integer

Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller) 
Set xLstBox = ActiveSheet.ListBox1 

xLstBox.List = MyList ' Insert Data from array to ListBox

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I10:R10") 'I must setting width,heigh and location because everytime i click the button the size become smaller and the position changed.
xLstBox.Width = 150
xLstBox.Height = 180
xLstBox.Top = rng.Top
xLstBox.Left = rng.Left

If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
    xLstBox.Visible = True
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Pickup Options"
Else
    xLstBox.Visible = False
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Options"
    For I = 0 To xLstBox.ListCount - 1

        If xLstBox.Selected(xLstBox.ListIndex) Then '<< This is the problem. Always return False
            xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & ";" & xSelLst
        End If
    Next I
    If xSelLst <> "" Then
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
    Else
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I look other people code and their using selected function too. can someone please help me, how to solve this problem. thank you.

Comment: I can't replicate it showing `False` but, ignoring that for the moment, what are you trying to do with that `If`?  It seems to be saying that if something is selected, you are setting `xSelLst` to be the string `"data11;data10;data9;...data2;data1;"`.  That seems to be a strange thing to do.  Aren't you interested in **what** was selected rather than just that **something** was selected?

Comment: xLstBox.Selected(xLstBox.ListIndex )  to   xLstBox.Selected(I)

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to get what was selected and print it. do you have another way to do that?

Comment: `xLstBox.List(xLstBox.ListIndex)`?

Comment: You are repopulating the listbox each time you click on the Rectangle2. I think repopulating the listbox make you loose your selection.

Comment: @YowE3K it didn't work.

Comment: @Vincent G can you please give me a solution Thank you

Comment: Either don't populate the listbox in the Rectangle2_Click event but somewhere else, or maybe move the populate inside the `If xLstBox.Visible = False Then ` branch (I suppose the listbox is initially hidden).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code Below

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rectangle2_Click()

Dim MyList(10) As String
MyList(0) = "data1"
MyList(1) = "data2"
MyList(2) = "data3"
MyList(3) = "data4"
MyList(4) = "data5"
MyList(5) = "data6"
MyList(6) = "data7"
MyList(7) = "data8"
MyList(8) = "data9"
MyList(9) = "data10"
MyList(10) = "data11"

Dim xSelShp As Shape
Dim xSelLst As Variant
Dim xLstBox As Object
Dim I As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set xLstBox = ListBox1

xLstBox.List = MyList ' Insert Data from array to ListBox

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I10:R10") 'I must setting width,heigh and location because everytime i click the button the size become smaller and the position changed.
xLstBox.Width = 150
xLstBox.Height = 180
xLstBox.Top = rng.Top
xLstBox.Left = rng.Left

If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
    xLstBox.Visible = True
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Pickup Options"
ElseIf xLstBox.Visible = True Then
xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Pickup Options"


    For I = 0 To xLstBox.ListCount - 1

        If xLstBox.Selected(I) Then 
            xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & ";" & xSelLst
        End If
    Next I
    If xSelLst <> "" Then
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
    Else
        Range("ListBoxOutput") = ""
    End If
    Else

xLstBox.Visible = False
    xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Options"
End If


End Sub
```

on Workbook open add the following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()



Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Select Options"
    Sheet1.ListBox1.Visible = False
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```